# XSLT: Group by and Filter based on a business logic

Tags: xslt, filter

My knowledge of XSLT is limited, so please forgive my ignorance. I am trying to create XML that has information about all failed steps across multiple execution servers. In the current setup,whenever a job is triggered, it can choose any of the available servers for execution. For each job failure that occurred during the day, an XML file is generated with details around the steps involved in execution. In the output summary XML, a step is considered failed based on the following rule:

<ERROR_CRITERIA>ALL</ERROR_CRITERIA> --- If the step fails across all the servers then it is considered failed.

<ERROR_CRITERIA>1</ERROR_CRITERIA> -- If it fails even on one server, it is considered failed.
Here is my input XML

```
<ERROR>
    <SERVER>
        <SERVERID>1</SERVERID>
        <ERROR_SUBID>1234</ERROR_SUBID>
        <VALIDATION>
            <STEP>1</STEP>
            <PURPOSE>test</PURPOSE>
            <ERROR_CRITERIA>ALL</ERROR_CRITERIA>
            <STATUS>SUCCESS</STATUS>
            <MESSAGE>SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED</MESSAGE>
        </VALIDATION>
        <VALIDATION>
            <STEP>2</STEP>
            <PURPOSE>test</PURPOSE>
            <ERROR_CRITERIA>1</ERROR_CRITERIA>
            <STATUS>FAILURE</STATUS>
            <MESSAGE>FAILED DUE TO NETWORK</MESSAGE>
        </VALIDATION>
    </SERVER>
    <SERVER>
        <SERVERID>2</SERVERID>
        <ERROR_SUBID>8765</ERROR_SUBID>
        <VALIDATION>
            <STEP>1</STEP>
            <PURPOSE>test1</PURPOSE>
            <ERROR_CRITERIA>ALL</ERROR_CRITERIA>
            <STATUS>FAILURE</STATUS>
            <MESSAGE>FAILED DUE TO ABC</MESSAGE>
        </VALIDATION>
        <VALIDATION>
            <STEP>2</STEP>
            <PURPOSE>test1</PURPOSE>
            <ERROR_CRITERIA>1</ERROR_CRITERIA>
            <STATUS>SUCCESS</STATUS>
            <MESSAGE>SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED</MESSAGE>
        </VALIDATION>
    </SERVER>
    <SERVER>
        <SERVERID>3</SERVERID>
        <ERROR_SUBID>8065</ERROR_SUBID>
        <VALIDATION>
            <STEP>1</STEP>
            <PURPOSE>test2</PURPOSE>
            <ERROR_CRITERIA>ALL</ERROR_CRITERIA>
            <STATUS>FAILURE</STATUS>
            <MESSAGE>FAILED DUE TO 123</MESSAGE>
        </VALIDATION>
        <VALIDATION>
            <STEP>2</STEP>
            <PURPOSE>test2</PURPOSE>
            <ERROR_CRITERIA>1</ERROR_CRITERIA>
            <STATUS>SUCCESS</STATUS>
            <MESSAGE>SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED</MESSAGE>
        </VALIDATION>
    </SERVER>
</ERROR>
```

I want to create  XML with OUTPUT as:

```
<ERROR>
        <VALIDATION>
            <STEP>2</STEP>
            <ERROR_CRITERIA>1</ERROR_CRITERIA>
            <STATUS>FAILURE</STATUS>
            <MESSAGE>SERVERID_1:FAILED DUE TO NETWORK.SERVER_2:SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED.SERVER_3:SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED</MESSAGE>
        </VALIDATION>
</ERROR>
```

Since a job could have any number of steps, the solution needs to be dynamic to allow for any number of steps and servers.

Since I am not experienced with XSLT, I am not sure if custom business logic can be integrated. If not, I am most likely to use Python to accomplish it.

XSLT version 1.0

Comment: The required logic is not clear: why is only `<STEP>2</STEP>` included in the output?

Comment: P.S. In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : In the input xml, STEP1 has an error criteria  <ERROR_CRITERIA>1</ERROR_CRITERIA>, which means if the step fails even in 1 server , it needs to be considered as failed.
Step 2 has error criteria as <ERROR_CRITERIA>ALL</ERROR_CRITERIA> which means it is considered failed if it fails on all the available servers.

Comment: OK. What about the XSLT version you can use?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Its 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow this correctly, you want do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="val" match="VALIDATION" use="STEP" />

<xsl:template match="/ERROR">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- for each distinct step -->
        <xsl:for-each select="SERVER/VALIDATION[count(. | key('val', STEP)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="grp" select="key('val', STEP)" />
            <xsl:if test="ERROR_CRITERIA = '1' and $grp/STATUS = 'FAILURE' or ERROR_CRITERIA = 'ALL' and not($grp/STATUS = 'SUCCESS')">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="STEP | ERROR_CRITERIA"/>
                    <STATUS>FAILURE</STATUS>
                    <MESSAGE>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$grp">
                            <xsl:text>SERVERID_</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../SERVERID"/>
                            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="MESSAGE"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </MESSAGE>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To understand how this works, you need to learn about [Muenchian grouping](https://%20http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

---

If it can be assumed that each SERVER lists all the steps, then you can simplify this by changing:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="SERVER/VALIDATION[count(. | key('val', STEP)[1]) = 1]">
```

to:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="SERVER[1]/VALIDATION">
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! However, the message part of the output only shows the text from the first server. For example, if i set the step 2 status as "FAILURE" in SERVER =3 , the output xml reflect error message from server 1 only <MESSAGE>SERVERID_1:FAILED DUE TO NETWORK.</MESSAGE>

Comment: That is not the result I get.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lspRy.png --- I am using my intellij setup to test this solution

Comment: There is something wrong with your testing environment. Or you are using a different code. Unfortunately, all the good online testers are currently down, but you can try https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/.

Comment: That's right, the issue was with the test environment. Thank you so much !!